# Click event on dynamicaly added images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm generating images from a folder with this script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    url: "gallery_images",
    success: function(data){
        $(data).find("a:contains(.jpg),a:contains(.gif),a:contains(.png)").each(function(){
            // will loop through
            var images = $(this).attr("href");

            $('<div class="g_image"></div>').html('<img class="g_img" src="gallery_images/'+images+'"/>').appendTo('#galerija');
        });
    }
});
```

});

The problem is that, then I'm trying to click the image, simple jQuery click event does not work.

```
$(".g_image img").click(function(){
alert("WORKING!");
```

});

Comment: @Zenith i stopped counting at 175 632 455, I'm tired now...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use event delegation for this, you can take closest parent document instead `document.body`

```
$(document.body).on("click","#g_image img",function(){
    alert("WORKING!");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

try using delegate.

```
$("body").on("click","#g_image img",function(){
 alert("WORKING!");

});
```